# display my feeds from facebook on my webpage with javascript api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-page

Im trying to get all the feed from my facebook page whit the javascript api.
Does anybody have a working example?

I have tryed but I cant get it right, I can get photos from albums, but I cant get the feeds and I dont know what Im doing wrong.

Any input really appreciated. Thanks!

I have this code:

---

## Edit

OK, I have the code inside the init code like below and it doesnt work, it is not executing the code and I get no errors:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<%=facebookAppId%>', // App ID
            channelUrl : 'www.mypage.se/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth      : true
        });

        // get the wall - feed
var page_id = '<%=facebookPageId%>';
    FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp2) {
        if(resp2.access_token) {
            alert(resp2.access_token);


 FB.api('/page id/feed?access_token='+resp2.access_token, function(response) {

    var ul = document.getElementById('feed');
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {

      var
      feed = response.data[i],
      li = document.createElement('li'),
      a = document.createElement('a');
      a.innerHTML = feed.message;
      a.href = feed.link;
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);
                       }
            });
        }
    }); 

 };//end window.fbAsyncInit

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));


</script>
```

1. So why can I have for example:
   FB.api('/facebook id', function(response) {
   alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
   });
   inside the init code and not the other code?
2. I would still need some structure help writing the callbacks out on the page so it looks good as it does on facebook.
   I like to write out "message, picture, link, name" and maybe something else?
3. As I test to get the messages in this example and some of the callback is displayed as "undefined" on the page? Does that mean that the message doesnt have a value when I get it?
   If so how can I not write out emty values - undefined ones?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

If I use this code then it reads the feed, but only if Im logged in to Facebook?
Im starting to get confused, since I think that the above code should work: 
I first ask for the access token in the first call, and when I get the access token, then using it in the second call, what Im I doing wrong?

```
FB.api('/my userid or pageid/feed?access_token=the acces token that I get from the Graph API Explorer', {limit:5} , function(response){
       if (response && response.data && response.data.length){
            alert(response.message);
            var ul = document.getElementById('feed');
          for (var j=0; j<response.data.length; j++){
            var feed = response.data[j],
            li = document.createElement('li'),
             a = document.createElement('a');
            a.innerHTML = feed.message;
            a.href = feed.link;
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
      });
```

1. I get a couple of undefined responses, how can I not write them out on the page?
2. How can I get the above code to work even if the user that visit the webpage is not logged in to facebook?
3. I make other calls that gets the photos of an album with no problem displaying them on the webpage, I dont understand why this is different?
4. If I want to set this up for a customer(when its finished) what are the steps I need to take? Getting a bit confused... :-)
5. I would like to get the message, picture, likes etc with the call
   and display it like it is on the feed-wall, any suggestions here?

Ok, finally I got it working :-)
I got the right acces token and now I can display the feeds.
I got the right token here:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myapp_id&client_secret=myapp_secret&grant_type=client_credentials
And now I can use the below code both for getting user feeds and page feeds, just changing the page_id!

```
var page_id = '<%=facebookPageId%>';
var pageaccessToken='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed?access_token='+ pageaccessToken, {limit:5} , function(response){
       if (response && response.data && response.data.length){

            var ul = document.getElementById('pagefeed');
          for (var j=0; j<response.data.length; j++){
            var feed = response.data[j],
            li = document.createElement('li'),
             a = document.createElement('a');
            a.innerHTML = feed.message;
            a.href = feed.link;
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
      });
```

Ok, now it works, but I get the undefined in the response?
What is causing this, is it because it is a empty value that I get in the response?
What can I do so it is not displayed on the page?

Comment: Do you have the "read_stream" permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what it is you're trying to do, I have the feeling though that you took the wrong path..

Let's start with the fact that you don't need any special permission or a page access token to query for the page feed, it's public and so all you need ([quoted from the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)) is: "any valid access_token or user access_token".
Which means that if a user authorized your application, you then acquired an access token for him and can get any page feed.
For example try the southpark page feed in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=southpark%2Ffeed).

Another issue is that asking the user for the "manage_pages" permission and then asking the graph api for the access token of **your own** app would not work. When a user grants your app to manage his pages that's exactly what you get, the permissions to **his** pages, and so this request for example: [/southpark?feilds=access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=southpark%3Ffields%3Daccess_token) won't get you the token since you are not the admin of this page (even if you grant the app with the "manage_pages" permission).

Last thing is the use of *window.onload*, which in your situation just does not address the problem.
You don't want to execute that code when the window is loaded but when the facebook sdk is loaded and intialized. That's why facebook tells you to use the *fbAsyncInit* event.
The code you had before the *window.onload* is the correct form, what exactly do you mean when you say "it didn't work"? Did you get any errors? It did not get executed?

---

## Edit

From what I understand you want to display the content of a facebook [Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) feed in your website.

As I already told you, all you need in order to get the feed of a page is an active access token ("any valid access_token or user access_token").

If you follow the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) doc, the App Login section you'll see that you can issue an access token for your facebook app. With that token you can then get the feed of *ANY PAGE* you want on the server side.

Comment: Hi Nitzan and thanks.
I want to be able to display one of my customers wall on their webpage and also display other things like, photo album, friends etc.

If I want to display anything else than the customers public stuff I need an access token. As it says her: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ "To get additional information about a user, you must first get their permission. At a high level, you need to get an access token for the Facebook user." 
The var page_id = 'my facebook page id'; is really the customers page id, not mine - a misstype. Ok, will not use window.onload

Comment: Wait, are you refering to a facebook user profile? You wrote "get all the feed from my **facebook page**" which means: [Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) and not [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). So which one is it?

Comment: Ok, now I have placed all the code inside window.fbAsyncInit and and it is not working, not displaying any feed info and no error.
It seams like its not executed.

Comment: ok, in this case I want to get the feeds from a PAGE, but later I want to get the feeds from a regular user as well.

Comment: I manage to get the following and displaying it on a webpage: Page name, page description, photos from an page album, name of page albums, but not the feed.

Comment: Those are different requests since your application can get the feed of a _Page_ just a user access token, you don't need any kind of additional permission, but in order to get the feed of a _User_ you need to get the "read_stream" permission. Can you edit your question with the code ?

Comment: Ok, maybe I was trying to make it more complicated than it is :-) 
I have updated the code now and it reads the message from the feed! But only if Im logged in to Facebook? Since I need an access token I thought that I would get it with the first call and use it in the second one, but it didnt work.
So just so I get it straight, when Im going to set this up for a customer is this what I have to do, Im getting a little confused :-). 1. Create an app so I get the app id, 2. Go to the Graph API Explorer and get a access token from there. 3. use the above code? Have I missed something?

Comment: No. You have a fb app, then a user logs in to your app and authorize it, because of that you get an access token from facebook (NO NEED TO MAKE A REQUEST FOR IT). You then use that token for all your requests (the FB JS SDK does that for you, no need to do it yourself) and then you simply make graph requests (such as _/southpark/feed) for the logged in user. If you want to request _/me/feed_ also then just ask for the read_stream permission.

Comment: Sorry Nitzan, but Im mixing things up I guess, before this I made some functions for uploading to Facebook, and thats why Im confused! So if I want to display the feeds on a webpage and that the visitor doesnt have to be logged in to Facebook. What do I have to do, step by step?
I have the app id, the userid and pageid.

Comment: You can't get the feed of the user if he's not logged in to facebook. The token you are given is a short lived token, once it has expired you can not use it anymore. If you are using the server side auth process then the tokens you get should live for a month.

Comment: Im trying to do this: I have a facebook PAGE and I have created a facebook app. And I want to display my facebook PAGE feeds on my webpage. So if I first log in to facebook with my PAGEID and then requests the access token from my PAGE, I then have a valid access token that I can use to get the feed.